# How to best get the parent of parent element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the parent of some deeply nested element like below

```
<div class='content  id='cart-content'>
  <div class='child1'>
       <div class='child1-1'>
           <div class='child1-1-1'>
               <input 
                 type="checkbox"
                 class='selectAllItem'
                 name='selectAllItem'
              /> Select All
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='child2'>
       <div class='child2-2'>
           <div class='child2-2-2'>
               <input 
                 type="checkbox"
                 class='selectOneItem'
                 name='selectOneItem'
              /> Select One
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i check `Select All` box I want to get the node of the root parent which have `id='cart-content'`

my approach
1.

```
let rootNode = event.target.closest('#cart-content')
```

but the problem is clicking on `select one checkbox` would also return same result because they both have same root parent and are on same level

approach 2.

```
let rootNode = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

the problem with this approach is the same if i click on `select one` checkbox would also return the root parent because the distance between the element and the root parent is also 4 parents

Now in `jquery` i would do the below to get desire result

`let rootNode = $(this).parent('.child1-1-1').parents('#');`

and when select one is clicked it won't return the rootNode because it doesn't have a direct parent with the class name `child1-1-1`

How can I achieve this same result using pure javascript vanilla js

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to solve the problem

1. get the immediate parent of the input field then check if it contails a specific class

   `var rootParentNode = e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('child1-1-1') ?  e.target.closest('#cart-content') : null;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to add an unique id to your input dynamically (not hard coding as I do below) and then just do what you want with the parentNode only if your input id is number 1, for instance (Select All) and nothing if it is number 2 (Select One).

Note that the event is listening to changes on check box, not to the checked status

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
    </h1>
    <div class="content" id="cart-content">
      <div class="child1">
        <div class="child1-1">
          <div class="child1-1-1">
            <input
              id="input1"
              type="checkbox"
              class="selectAllItem selectinput"
              name="selectAllItem"
            />
            Select All
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="child2">
        <div class="child2-2">
          <div class="child2-2-2">
            <input
              id="input2"
              type="checkbox"
              class="selectOneItem selectinput"
              name="selectOneItem"
            />
            Select One
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    let allInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("selectinput");

    allInputs = [...allInputs];
    allInputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        let parentNode;
        if (e.target.id == "input1") {
          parentNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
          // Do something with parentNode
          console.log(parentNode)
          }
          else{
          // Do something else
          }
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks alot for your time, i think of other way to solve this problem which definetely invlove conditional check, i was actually thinking before there'sa methos provided by javascript to accomplish this task

Comment: Alright. No, I don´t know of any methods to get that parentNode directly, sorry